# Unable to reset iframe content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an iframe whose src file (given below) contains a form which uses _self target.  The action returns a text string.  After it has been submitted, I would like to reload the iframe with the original content if the mouse leaves the form or user types ESC.

I can't get the iframe to reset itself.  Any help appreciated.  This is the 'master' html file:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>iframe test</title>


<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
function foo(e){
   $('iframe.popup').css('display','block');
   $(e.target).css('z-index','10');
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var popup = $(document).find(".popup");
    popup[0].origSrc = popup[0].src; // save orignal content of iframe

    $(document).keyup(function(e) {
        if ( //e.keyCode == 13 ||     // enter
            e.keyCode == 27) {     // esc
          $(document).find(".popup").hide();
        }  
      });
    $(".floatbar").click(function(e){
        if (e.target.className == "floatbar"){
          e.preventDefault();
        }
        else {
          return true;
        }
        popup = $(this).find(".popup");

        popup.empty();
        popup.load(popup[0].origSrc);

        popup.show();//fadeIn("slow");
        popup.mouseleave(function(e){
            //$(this).fadeOut("fast");
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).empty();
          });
        popup.keydown(function(e){
            if ( e.keyCode == 27 ){
              $(this).hide();
              $(this).empty();

            }
          });
      });


});
</script>
<style>
.popup {
         position:absolute;
         border:1em;
         top:0px;
         font-size: 2.0em;
         display:none;
         text-decoration: none;
         z-index: 5;
}
iframe.login { 
                background: darkblue;
                width: 300%;
                min-height:400px;
                }

form { 
       color: white; 
       list-style-type: none;
       }

</style>
</head>
<body>

<a class="floatbar" href="#">Some text

<iframe class="popup login" src="register.close.html"></iframe>
</a>
</body> </html>
```

File 'register.close.html':

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <form name="registration" action="../php/register.php" method="post" 
 accept-charset="utf-8" target="_self"  >  
     <div> 
       <p><label for="submit"> Hi</label> 
         <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Register" > 
       </p> 
     </div> 
 </form> 
</body> </html>
```

Thanks again.

Comment: Couldn't you just reload the iframe with `$("#iframe").attr("src", $("#iframe").attr("src"));`

Comment: I did and it worked.  Thanks.  Still confused about why load doesn't work.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't know why load doesn't work. However in programing I like to follow a simple rule: KISS, Keep It Simple Stupid.  Pretty much, don't make anything more complicated than it has to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reload an iframe I just use the following code.

```
$("#iframe").attr("src", $("#iframe").attr("src"));
```

All this does is set the iframe's `src` attribute to itself. This causes it to reload.